# How to display preview app within a mobile image

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, frontend

does anyone know a way or a plugin that could help me displaying a preview of my web app within a mobile image (iphone or android)
[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Google Chrome as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) although Google recommends testing on real devices.

1. In the console, click this icon to show the device toolbar or hit `Ctrl+Shift+M` while in the console.

   [image]
2. Click the dots on the toolbar to open settings
   [image]
3. Click "Show device frame"

In the device dropdown, if you click "Edit" then you can select more devices to show.

[image]